# Как поменять иконку приложения на панели задач, но не формы?

Tags: windows, delphi, иконки

Подскажите, как сменить иконку на панели задач так, чтобы иконка формы (form.icon) осталась неизменной?

`Application.Icon.Assign()` меняет иконку и там и там. И даже если после смены к примеру принудительно изменить `form.icon` - то ничего не происходит...

Answer (score 1):

Установите свойство `Application.MainFormOnTaskbar` в значение `False`. Это укажет, что для кнопки на панели задач, заголовок и иконку надо брать не из главной формы, а использовать свойства невидимого окна `Application`.

Пример

Устанавливаем в файле `.dpr` (*project/view source*).

```
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.Title := 'Заголовок кнопки';
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := False;   // меняем на false
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.Run;
```

В основной форме при создании формы

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Icon.LoadFromFile('с:\temp\1.ico');

  Application.Icon.LoadFromFile('с:\temp\2.ico');
end;
```

Результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если честно не совсем понял как это связанно, но попробовал. Ничего не изменилось, по прежнему при смене иконки application меняется и иконка form.

Comment: Добавил пример кода и скрин результата

Comment: То есть всякий раз, когда нам нужно поменять только иконку приложения нам нужно дополнительно менять иконку формы.
Ну, к примеру вот так Icon.LoadFromResourceName(HInstance, 'MAINICON'); - чтобы восстановить изначальную иконку.
Не сказать, что это очень изящное решение, но уже что-то.

Comment: Но тут дело в другом, я полез в исходники основого проекта, и вижу там, что Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := true;
И поменять это никак нельзя, поскольку в проекте заложен функционал thumbnails и прочее, и если это отключить, то, согласно документации http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Forms_TApplication_MainFormOnTaskBar.html этот функционал попросту перестанет работать.